# openstack nova-compute : How to set resource limits?

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

I am running openstack queens. When I fire up nova-compute, I see the following in my logs which indicates that nova-compute assumes I have a 15gb disk.

```
Final resource view: name=compute01.learningneutron.com phys_ram=11998MB used_ram=512MB phys_disk=15GB used_disk=0GB total_vcpus=16 used_vcpus=0 pci_stats=[]
```

However I do df, I see I have much more space than 15 gb.

How do I configure nova-compute to utilize this space? Do I need to set up cinder? All I want to do is to use the local filesystem.

Thanks. Ranga

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nova stores disk images on the Hypervisor in the directory specified by the **instances_path** directive in the configuration files, the default value is **/var/lib/nova/instances**.

Can you check what is the disk space allocated to this partition.

Comment: You can use `df -h` to see your partitions, and make sure that /var/ or /var/lib/ is big enough to accommodate your use case.